# How can I create a tracking id in prisma

Tags: schema, prisma

I want to create a tracking ID like a custom string as a prefix and a uuid. e.g.
My string "FDL" then uuid like "sdsad-2321-432e2-3434".
This should be something like: **FDL-sdsad-2321-432e2-3434**

I have something like this in mind.

```
model Shipments{
  id                         Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
  tracking_id                String               @default(dbgenerated("FDL-" + uuid()))
  }
```

Any help please?